# Spring MVC Reflection - invoke Pojo setters

Tags: spring, reflection, spring-mvc

I have a controller that is supposed to update any object in the database, how can I make it so that that objects setters are called based on the property keys of that object?
I have heard that reflection might be the answer to my prays, is that so, and if so, what is the most elegant way to achieve what I'm looking for?

```
    Object entity = repository.findOne(id);

    for (Object key : request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
        //invoke setter-method of entity
        //for example, if key == "name" , i want entity.setName() to be called
    }

    repository.save(entity)
```

I'm running Spring MVC. If more info is needed please let me know!

**UPDATE, working code:**

```
Object entity = repository.findOne(id);
BeanWrapper beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(entity);
    for (Object key : request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
            beanWrapper.setPropertyValue(key.toString(), request.getParameterMap().get(key));
    }

    repository.save(entity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to the same data binding facilities that Spring MVC uses to implement `@ModelAttribute`, etc.

```
new WebDataBinder(entity).bind(new ServletRequestParameterPropertyValues(request));
```

Note that this approach imposes specific format of parameter names, as described in [5.4 Bean manipulation and the BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used the BeanWrapper-approach and it worked great.